# NSCollectionView - Not able to tab through fields after first row

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

My `NSCollectionView` uses a custom `NSCollectionViewItem` which contains 2 `NSComboBox`, 1 `NSTextField` and 1 `NSDatePicker`. When running my app and displaying multiple `NSCollectionViewItems`, I am able to tab through the comboboxes and the textfield of the first item, but none of the items that follow. If I select the textfield in the second or third item and hit the tab key, nothing happens.

I would like to tab through each component in my `NSCollectionViewItem` and then continue through to the next component in the next `NSCollectionViewItem`. I expected this to be the default behavior.

Because it works for the first item in my `NSCollectionView`, I know that it can work for the rest.

Is there something I need to set while `NSCollectionView` is displaying the items?

Comment: hey did you find any solution for this? i am kind of stuck with similar issue, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on Recalculates View Loop of the window. Side effect: `nextKeyView` of the views isn't used.